Проблема с модулем gpsdclient
Я пытюсь запустить программу со страницы pip'а но появляется ошибка.
from gpsdclient import GPSDClient

# get your data as json strings:
with GPSDClient(host="127.0.0.1") as client:
    for result in client.json_stream():
        print(result)

# or as python dicts (optionally convert time information to `datetime` objects)
with GPSDClient() as client:
    for result in client.dict_stream(convert_datetime=True, filter=["TPV"]):
        print("Latitude: %s" % result.get("lat", "n/a"))
        print("Longitude: %s" % result.get("lon", "n/a"))

# you can optionally filter by report class
with GPSDClient() as client:
    for result in client.dict_stream(filter=["TPV", "SKY"]):
        print(result)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\py_pycharm\location\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    for result in client.json_stream():
  File "F:\py_pycharm\location\.venv\Lib\site-packages\gpsdclient\client.py", line 74, in json_stream
    for line in self.gpsd_lines():
  File "F:\py_pycharm\location\.venv\Lib\site-packages\gpsdclient\client.py", line 63, in gpsd_lines
    self.sock = socket.create_connection(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\socket.py", line 852, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python312\Lib\socket.py", line 837, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение

Возможно проблема в том что в параметре host я указываю '127.0.0.1' но так было на сайте и в документации про это ничего нет.
Если испольщовать команду в теринале появляется таже ошибка:
(.venv) PS F:\py_pycharm\location> .\.venv\Scripts\python.exe -m gpsdclient
[WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение
(.venv) PS F:\py_pycharm\location> 


Ну так а где крутится gpsd сервис, к которому вы хотите подключиться? В примере он видимо на локальном хосте прямо крутился. gpsdclient - это клиент, который коннектится к сервису gpsd на сервере. Если у вас нет сервиса на сервере, то вам некуда коннектиться.

и еще не понятно, что такое "страница pip'a".
